# Valid character subset of extended ASCII for javascript strings

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, extended-ascii

I am doing some experiments with data encoding. I know there is already a base64 format, but I would like something taking less space. Please, note, I am asking for the particular characters, not just their counts.
1. What character subset of extended ASCII can be represented by Javascript string?
2. What character subset of extended ASCII can be represented by Javascript string without the need of escaping assuming " characters are used around the string data?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you found or tried so far?

Comment: That is not homework - it is still holiday time:) I could try all the characters tediously and find out which ones they are but this could be prone to human mistakes, would take much time and might not be compatible across the platforms. Mostly I searched for a documentation, but I could not find the relevant information.

Comment: "Extended ASCII" isn't a real encoding.

Comment: I am sure there are definitely more than 64 characters, ' ', '=', '+', '-' and so on. The compatibility across the platforms might be an issue and since I do not have the knowledge of standards, I am asking people with a greater insight.

Comment: By Extended ASCII I mean the encoding which uses one byte for one character.

Comment: There are *hundreds* of encodings, most of which use one byte per character.  Please narrow it down.

Comment: There is no “extended ASCII”. Question 1 makes little sense, as any Unicode (or at least any BMP) character may appear in a string. Question 2 makes little sense too, as it does not specify what is really meant by “escaping” here.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, extended ASCII is any encoding that: 1. encodes first 128 characters like ASCII, 2. uses one byte per character. And there are many such encodings and therefore what I would like to do would not be platform independent but would rely on their encoding settings in the system.

Comment: Extended ASCII is a subrange of ASCII character set rather than encoding. The characters between 128 to 255 inclusive (0x80-0xFF). Character representation dependends on the code page and OS which can be different on every systems. For example, the *Windows U.S. English*, and *DOS U.S. English* code pages. Both have different character set for the Extended ASCII. ISO character sets, on the other hand, is platform independent regardless the actual number of characters may be greater than 256. In this case, only the first 256 character codes are used if ASCII is to be used.